# WEKA: Training a classifier and running test set on learned classifier (knowledge flow)

Tags: machine-learning, weka

I have to following situation:

I train a classifier using a dataset and cross-validation:

[image]

Now I want to read another file (dataset) with unlabeled instances and want them to be classified by the classifier (`SMO`) that was learnt right before (with the first dataset).

I probably need another `ArffLoader`, `ClassAssigner`, `TextViewer` and one or two other components (but I couldn't find any suitable ones for this task).